# Unable to proxy_pass from nginx to traefik behind ELB

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, traefik

This is the setup I'm faced with:

- There is a Kubernetes cluster with Traefik service deployed. The traefik service handles all the communication to other services inside the Kubernetes cluster, i.e. the main proxy.
- The traefik service is the only service with external IP of type LoadBalancer

I need to point a different server (outside of the Kubernetes cluster) to the Traefik endpoint, i.e. I wish to expose through routing of the external server applications inside the Kubernetes cluster. The external server is using nginx.

I've set up all the applications and routes in traefik to expect the hostname "example.com". Then I went to the external server (example.com) and set nginx.conf

```
location / {
            proxy_pass https://load_balancer_dns;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

where "load_balancer_dns" is the hostname for the application load balancer for the Traefik service.

My expectation is, that when I reach example.com, the nginx will forward the request to the load balancer, which will call the Traefik pod, which will finally dissect the hostname and path and call the correct service pod and return the response. However, I'm getting 418 errors, meaning the route is not matched in Traefik.

After a bit of debugging, it seems that Traefik ignores the host header and considers the host to be "load_balancer_dns", which is the cause of 418. Is there a way to configure nginx such that Traefik will understand the host is "example.com" instead of "load_balancer_dns"?

Comment: From the [`kubernetes` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes): "*KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE DEVELOPMENT RELATED. ...*" --- This question might be better suited for [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out in the end. The reason is in the traefik routes. I was using "Host(`example.com`)" which is not enough due to changes made in this PR https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/7008. The check for Host is both the header host check and the server name indication. If switched to "HostHeader(`example.com`)" only header host is checked, which is enough for the nginx proxy.